# Appengine Task Queue Stored Task Count > 0 but no tasks are entering tasks queue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I have created a process that generated a lot of tasks for the task queue.
After the queues cleared up, I still have 7600 tasks appearing in the "Task Queue Stored Task Count" but no new tasks are queuing/running in any of my queues (See image)

Is that normal or is it stuck? shouldn't it be 0?
Could someone explain the relationship between the Task Queue Stored Task Count queue to the actual tasks queue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is your application's daily quota status for Task Queue API. This will shows how many task you have stored in a day.

Daily quotas are refreshed daily at midnight Pacific time.

To know more about Appengine Quota: [Click Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en_US)

Comment: Unlike the top line, this doesn't seem like a daily quota as it usually decrements to 0 while pushing the tasks to the queue.
I have just confirmed this by running a job that creates more tasks and it decremented from 500 to 0 while the queue was processing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be that the stored tasks have `etaMillis`  or `countdownMillis` set to some point in the future and so have not been pushed to the TaskQueue. I am seeing the same result upon adding a new Task set to be executed in the future. But this behaviordoes not seem to be documented anywhere. Ideally, the tasks 'scheduled' this way should show up somewhere even if they have not been pushed to the Queue yet - much like the Cron Jobs do.